# How to assign a SetState function in a component? (NextJS and TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, next.js, components, setstate

I am learning TypeScript and I am stuck on the correct assignment for my `setState` that I pass to a component.

```
/index.tsx

import { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useState } from "react";
import FetchPokeAPI from "./api/FetchPokeAPI";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import ItemList from "./components/ItemList";

export interface IAllItems {
  name: string;
  url: string;
} [];

export default function Home() {

  const [allItems, setAllItems] = useState<IAllItems[]>([]);

  FetchPokeAPI(setAllItems);

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <ItemList items={allItems} />
    </>
  )
}
```

```
/FetchPokeAPI.tsx

import { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useEffect } from "react";
import { IAllItems } from "./../index";

interface IProps {
    setAllItems: Dispatch<SetStateAction<IAllItems[]>>;
    allItems: IAllItems[];
}

export default function FetchPokeAPI({setAllItems}:IProps) {
  const pokeapiURL:string = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/item/";

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(pokeapiURL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setAllItems(data.results);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }, [pokeapiURL]);
}
```

I get this message:

```js
Argument of type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<IAllItems[]>>'
  is not assignable to parameter of type 'IProps'
```

Thanks in advance :)

Other forum posts have helped me a bit, but now I can't get any further.

Answer (score 0):

because interface IProps contains 2 elements: setAllItems: Dispatch<SetStateAction<IAllItems[]>> & allItems: IAllItems[];
and you are assigning it to only setAllItems, as you didn't put your second element, allItems, in the props, you only put it in the type interface

```
export default function FetchPokeAPI({setAllItems}:IProps) {...
```

so typescript sees 2 different types, type IProps which is

```
{
    setAllItems: Dispatch<SetStateAction<IAllItems[]>>;
    allItems: IAllItems[];
}
```

and type of the current props which is

```
{
    setAllItems: Dispatch<SetStateAction<IAllItems[]>>;
}
```

so, you need to put allItems in your props

```
export default function FetchPokeAPI({setAllItems, allItems}:IProps) {...
```

and you get a correct type assignment